# How can I validate only specific fields when doing update_attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a `User` model, where are following validations

```
validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :password, :confirmation => true
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

validates_presence_of :bnet_username, :on => :update
validates_presence_of :bnet_code, :on => :update
```

The reason why `bnet_username` and `bnet_code` is only on update is because I already had existing users when I added those fields and they're not in the registration form, so I only need users to set them once they're registered on the website.

There is one problem though, and that is when a user without set `bnet_username` and `bnet_code` tries to reset his password. In that case, the `PasswordResetController` will try to update his attributes, but the validation will fail.

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset! You can now log in."
...
```

The problem is, I need to validate password when user tries to reset it, but I don't want to validate it when he's just updating his profile.

I also can't skip the validation all together on the password reset, because I need to validate the password itself.

**Is there any simple solution on how to say which just which validations I need to run? Or am I approaching this completely wrong?**

**edit**: Basically there is one case when this causes problems. Existing user who didn't yet set his `bnet_username` and `bnet_code`, but he wants to change his password.

Since change of password is an update action, it will trigger validations for `bnet_username` and `bnet_password`. But I need them to be set on update only, because I want users to set them when they edit their profile.

It's not a mandatory field when user is registering, but they have to set it when they try to update profile information.

Comment: Please expand a little more on "but I don't want to validate it when he's just updating his profile.".  I get wrapped up in some funny logic myself there and the other parts of the question are about whether 2 bnet fields are set, not sure which takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
validates_presence_of :bnet_username, :on => :update, 
  :if => Proc.new { |user| !user.bnet_username.blank? }
validates_presence_of :bnet_code, :on => :update,
  :if => Proc.new { |user| !user.bnet_code.blank? }
```

Comment: well yes, but the problem is when user doesn't have `bnet_code` set and wants to reset his password, in which case this will fail too

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `:if` and `:unless` parameters to the validations, with which you can define when you want to validate that specific field.

Example:

```
:validate_presence_of :email, :unless => Proc.new { |user| user.signup_step <= 2 })
```